# Emacs: viewing space/tab symbols

Tags: emacs

In Notepad++ there is an amazingly handy button I can press to see symbols where spaces, tabs, and newlines are so I can see which whitespaces are caused by spaces and which are caused by tabs. Can I do this in emacs? If not, how does one generally go about testing in emacs whether a file you are reading separates strings by spaces or tabs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [WhiteSpace](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace) package does this. It will show tab, space and newline combinations in your code.

Some [alternatives](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace#toc10) exist.

Comment: This package is bundled with Emacs 23, for older versions download and install.

Comment: i don't see a clear explanation on that page for how to activate whitespace mode? what's the command?

Comment: @hatorade `M-x whitespace-mode`

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want -- there are several possibilities: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShowWhiteSpace